# Извлечь из строки такое-то по счёту число

Tags: lua

Есть строка: "123 123 123456 7 () 89"

Из этой строки мне нужно получить значение 7, все остальное нужно убрать.

При этом между цифрами может быть разное количество пробелов, от 1 до 8.

После 7 могут идти пробел, скобки и еще несколько цифр, строка динамическая, поэтому проще парсить от начала.

Числа все могут быть разными, от 1 до 100. %d нужно спарсить, проще говоря.

Нужно спарсить 4 по счету.

Comment: По какому принципу "нужно получить значение 7"? Из вопроса непонятно, чем, например, не устраивает вариант просто взять последний символ строки?

Comment: После 7 могут идти пробел, скобки, и еще несколько цифр , строка динамическая, поэтому проще парсить от начала

Comment: И опять непонятно. Нужно получить четвертое по счету число? Или число из одной цифры?

Comment: Числа все могут быть разными, от 1 до 100, %d нужно спарсить если проще говоря. Нужно спарсить 4 по счету.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "123 123 123456 7 () 89"

counter = 0

for n in s:gmatch("%d+") do
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == 4 then
        result = n
        break
    end
end

print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Решение, оформленное в виде функции и с немного упрощённой логикой:

```
function selectnum(str, cnt)
    local iter = str:gmatch("%d+")
    local res
    for i=1,cnt do res = iter() end
    return res
end
```

Проверка:

```
print(selectnum('123 123 123456 7 () 89', 1)) -- 123
print(selectnum('123 123 123456 7 () 89', 2)) -- 123
print(selectnum('123 123 123456 7 () 89', 3)) -- 123456
print(selectnum('123 123 123456 7 () 89', 4)) -- 7
print(selectnum('123 123 123456 7 () 89', 5)) -- 89
print(selectnum('123 123 123456 7 () 89', 6)) -- nil
```